# Laravel RESTful API with Android app

Tags: android, api, rest, session, laravel-5

I'm developing an Android app and a RESTful API with Laravel 5 Framework.
I've got a trouble with the login activity: the flow is that the user ask a 8th characters code and the server web sends him a SMS with it. Then user can do the login using this code like a password.

This is the code that asks a code:

```
private void askCode(String mobile) {
    GsonRequest<String> jsObjRequest = new GsonRequest<String>(
            Request.Method.GET,
            WebAPIRoute.authGetCode + "/" + mobile,
            String.class, null,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String code) {
                    txtResponse.setText("Code asked successfully.");
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    this.requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

And this the method in the RESTful API to generate a code:

```
public function getCode($mobileNum)
{       
    //genero un numero casuale da mandare con l'sms
    $code = mt_rand(10000000, 99999999);

    Session::put('code', $code);

    sendCode($mobileNum, $code); //send code by SMS

    return response()->json(array("success"=>true));
}
```

The code generated is stored into Laravel's Session (configurated with file driver).
When the user wants to login, the app call this method:

```
private void saveUser(final String code, final String mobile, final String name) {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    params.put("nickname", name);
    params.put("mobile", mobile);
    params.put("code", code);

    GsonRequest<String> jsObjRequest = new GsonRequest<String>(
            Request.Method.POST,
            WebAPIRoute.authValidateCode,
            String.class,
            params,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String authtoken) {
                    final Account account = new Account(accountName, mAccountType);

                    String authtokenType = mAuthTokenType;
                    // Creating the account on the device and setting the auth token we got
                    // (Not setting the auth token will cause another call to the server to authenticate the user)
                    mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, code, null);
                    mAccountManager.setAuthToken(account, authtokenType, authtoken);

                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                    data.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    data.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, mAccountType);
                    data.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authtoken);
                    data.putString(PARAM_USER_PASS, code);
                    data.putBoolean(ARG_IS_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT, true);

                    final Intent res = new Intent();
                    res.putExtras(data);

                    setAccountAuthenticatorResult(res.getExtras());

                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyEventsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            ,
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, volleyError.getMessage(), volleyError);
                    showMessage("Errore nell'autenticazione. Riprova piu` tardi.");
                }
            });

    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

The method of API that validate the code is this:

```
public function validateCode() {
    $code = trim(Input::get('code'));
    $nickName = trim(Input::get('nickname'));
    $phoneNum = trim(Input::get('mobile'));

    if (empty($phoneNum))
        abort(400, 'mobile parameters not provided.');

    if (empty($code))
        abort(400, 'code parameters not provided.');

    if (empty($nickName))
        abort(400, 'nickname parameters not provided.');

    $validCode = Session::get('code');
    Log::info('code: ' . $code . " validCode: " . $validCode);

    if($code == $validCode) {
        Session::forget('code');

        // Retrieve the user by the attributes, or instantiate a new instance...
        $user = User::firstOrCreate(['Mobile' => $phoneNum]);

        //aggiorno i campi nickname e password col nuovo codice
        $user->Nickname = $nickName;
        $user->password = $code;

        //save!
        $user->save();

        //viene usata l'autenticazione di Laravel e gli serve una password
        $token = JWTAuth::attempt(['Mobile' => $phoneNum, 'password' => $code]);

        return response()->json($token);
    } else {
        //return response()->json(array('success' => false, 'error' => 'The code isn\'t correct.'));
        abort(401, 'The code isn\'t correct.' . $validCode);
    }
}
```

I've tested the RESTful API with Chrome and Firefox and the login works. With the app no. Infact the issue is that Session::get('code'); in validateCode returns always an empty value. I checked the Session file generated with Session::put('code', $code); and is correct. But when Session::get('code') is called, Laravel generates another Session file and seems not use the previous.
I disabled the CSRF Middleware in RESTful API.

What is wrong?

Comment: not use session in restful, add a token and control it in code.

Comment: I don't understand.. when I have to add a token? And who generates this token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing the session on the server side is pointless. API's are suppose to be stateless so the second you finish the first request for the code and store it in a session on the server side, the session will end and the next request will not remember anything you set.

If you wanted to keep the code login and avoid using tokens, then you will have to send a unique code from the android app which identifies the user. Then generate the code on the server side and store it in a table with user_identifier and generated_code and create a model to access it e.g.

**AttemptedLogin**

user_id | generatedCode

---

0001 | 87392042

0032 | 83214320

Then on add this to saveUser

```
params.put("user_id", user_id); // can be the android device ID or even a unique timestamp
```

Finally on the server side in validateCode replace $validCode line with the following:

```
$user_id = trim(Input::get('user_id')); 

....

$validCode = AttemptedLogin::where('user_id', $user_id)->first();

if($code == $validCode->generatedCode) {
    $validCode->delete();

....
```

Comment: I did it in this way. Thanks a lot!